# How can I prevent nohup from creating the file ~/nohup.out?

Tags: command-line, nohup

I use the command `$ nohup ...` to start an application in the background so that I can close the terminal window afterwards.

Upon execution it creates the file `~/nohup.out`.

**Example:**

```
orschiro@x230:~$ nohup /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /home/orschiro/bin/show_state.py"
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

**How can I prevent `nohup` from creating `nohup.out`?**

Comment: You might also consider `byobu`. :)

Comment: Thank you, @AndreaLazzarotto! Can you give me an example how to use it?

Comment: Well, I suggest you have a look at the video here: http://byobu.co/ Basically, for what you want to do you just run `byobu`, start whatever you want, then press `F6` and you are done. You can get back to it by running `byobu` again.

Comment: Excellent! You might want to add this as an official answer?

Comment: Technically, my suggestion does not answer your question at all, it is just an alternative. :D

Comment: Yet a very nice one! ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may redirect the output anywhere you like, for example:

```
nohup /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /home/orschiro/bin/show_state.py" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

redirection prevents the default output file `nohup.out` from being created. `/dev/null` is oblivion, so if you don't want the data at all, send it there.

In bash you can abbreviate `>/dev/null 2>&1` to `&>/dev/null`

For programs I use often I make an alias (and add it to my `.bashrc`) for example

```
alias show_state='nohup /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /home/orschiro/bin/show_state.py" >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

Now all I have to type is `show_state`

Comment: @orschiro: After a few years it won't be cryptic and you'll remember it ;) I suggest sticking with it, because aliasing it away means you won't gain that experience, and knowing how BASH redirection operators work off the top of your head is a crucial skill.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better off as a function? Something like `show_state () { /bin/bash -c "$@" &>/dev/null }`? (Warning: poor syntax and probably won't work! It's just an example!). One nitpick: why `show_state` when you're throwing away the output of `nohup`?

Comment: I don't know what the script does @IsmaelMiguel but I assume it is an indicator with a tray icon, not to print "state" (whatever it is) to stdout. Sure, a function may well be more fun than an alias ^.^

Comment: Oh, I got it! Sorry, didn't see the name of the `.py` file. And yes, a function is more fun. I have this badly written function on a Debian desktop: `shutup() { source "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 & }`. And it works. Maybe you could suggest something similar, but a lot better?

Comment: I never knew that `&>` worked (and to my mind it looks like background plus stdout redirection). I always learned it as `>&`. Is it standard?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel it's your idea, why don't you add an answer ;)

Comment: @Random832 `&>outfile` is a bash-ism, `>outfile 2>&1` is standard

Comment: How does redirection work if a `nohup.out` file is created instead of standard output?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος nifty feature of `nohup`... read the source code and get back to us :)

Comment: @Zanna Where is the source code exactly? I can only find a binary, a man page, and a [nohup.c](//opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-118/nohup/nohup.c) (note: this is for OS X as far as I can tell) without the `FILE` datatype. Strange...

Comment: @orschiro you need to remember it this way: first redirect standard output (`>`) to `/dev/null`, then redirect standard error (`2>`) to standard output (`&1`).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος nohup.c is the source code (in coreutils package source)

Comment: @Zanna I am talking about `&> outfile` vs `>& outfile`. I can't find a description of `>& outfile`, but `io_file : GREATAND filename` does appear in the [official grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) - anyway, it's supported more widely on actual shells other than bash, so it's probably better to learn it than `&>` in any case.

Comment: On reviewing the standard further I was able to determine that the behavior is unspecified. It does give a more informative error than `&>` in dash (which does indeed interpret the latter as "background, then redirect [for a second, null, command]") though.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The behavior of only opening `nohup.out` if the existing standard output is a terminal is standard, see [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html), so you can rely on it on most systems including OSX. It will also automatically redirect stderr to stdout if you only redirected stdout, so you can just do `nohup ... > /dev/null`.

Comment: Because your answer was already upvoted and accepted. Adding an answer showing an alternative would be pretty much useless. Nobody would even care about it. That's why I don't post an answer.